# escape wildcard processing in java classpath

Tags: java, windows, shell, cmd

Next code prints attributes of each file in current directory because of wildcard processing.

```
c:\work>attrib *
```

I need to disable wildcard processing in my script. Escape symbols dont work:

```
c:\work>attrib "*"
c:\work>attrib ^*
```

Both give you the same.

I need to disable wildcard processing to start my application that accept wildcard as an argument.

A.java

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(args));
    }
}
```

CMD

```
C:\work\temp>start.bat

C:\work\temp>java -cp playground.jar A *
[activation.jar, file.txt, playground.jar, playground.jar.bak, start.bat, test.bat]

C:\work\temp>start.bat

C:\work\temp>java -cp playground.jar A "*"
[activation.jar, file.txt, playground.jar, playground.jar.bak, start.bat, test.bat]

C:\work\temp>start.bat

C:\work\temp>java -cp playground.jar A "* foo? *bar*"
[* foo? *bar*]
```

---

Found workaround. "*;" - not falid folder name, but valid classpath:

```
java -cp "*;" A
```

Thanks.

Comment: But... under Windows the shell isn't responsible for wildcard expansion...

Comment: are you saying that it is not feasible to disable wildcard processing in windows shell script?

Comment: I agree with Ignacio. Have you tried creating a simple console application, passing in a * and checking for it in the args?

Comment: I'm saying that it's not *necessary* since *it never processes them in the first place*.

Comment: It corrupts arguments of my app I need to disable it somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams already notes, on Windows the shell *does not do wildcard expansion*. That's up to the application. So there is nothing you can do to the shell to stop it from doing something that it doesn't do in the first place.

```
> echoargs.exe *
arg 1: *
```

So if the arguments in your application are corrupted somehow, then it's definitely not the shell's fault.

**EDIT:** Apparently Java "helpfully" copies the Unix behaviour and expands all wildcards for you. Above `echoargs` was written in C#, which is why the problem didn't show.

Ok, further digging reveals [this bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5036373) from 2004. This is because Java was linked with a different version of `setargv`, as described [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bch7bkk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and thus expands wildcards in command-line arguments. This happens before Java even sees the arguments because this is the C runtime startup code.

Furthermore, this is not documented anywhere as far as I could find, bug 5036373 linked above even notes that it *should* be documented. No fix for that, apparently. Even though it makes it impossible to pass a literal wildcard to Java programs. Apparently Windows is indeed just a second-class target for Java and they don't care (or it would break too many programs, but I'm not sure there are that many that explicitly rely on this behaviour).

Comment: It works for you because "* foo? \*bar\*" is not valid folder name, plese try single *

Comment: See edit. The shell isn't a fault, neither is Windows. It's Java. (And those are three arguments, the first of which is an asterisk.)

Comment: could you show autput of your app with single \* as an argument pls

Comment: It's as if you'd expect it. I told you, the shell does not to wildcard expansion and neither does any other part of Windows by default, excepting those functions who do so by design (e.g. `FindFirstFile`).

Comment: it is not Java neither, because wildcard in classpath is signifficant, well cocumented feature, and it works correctly in unix. Users face issues in windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441112/java-command-line-arguments-using-as-an-argument-for-multiplication

Comment: Windows 7, Java 1.7u3 64-bit. And you need to quote the classpath if you include an `*`. Otherwise on Unix the shell *would* expand it.

Comment: Huh? You were looking for a *classpath*? I was under the impression that normal arguments gave you headaches.

Comment: classpath was original problem, then I've figured out that it is cmd processing, thus I've done simplest program that reveal that processing and started to play with it.